# Do I have to use Google Cloud Platform to integrate Android zero-touch enrollment API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, android-enterprise

I've already developed an EMM solution that migrated on Microsoft Azure. Now, I want to integrate Android zero-touch enrollment API and Android Management API into my solution. According to the [document](https://developers.google.com/zero-touch/guides/customer/quickstart/dotnet), I can use Google Cloud Platform  to run the API, but is it compulsory? If I use it, all my new create data will save on Google Cloud, so can I move those data to my current Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the API you will need a GCP account as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/zero-touch/guides/customer/quickstart/dotnet) you shared.

However this is only required to call the API. If ou want your application to be hosted on a different cloud that can work, just need the GCP account to generate the API key in order to use the Zero-touch API.